# Synchronizing root filesystems

Tags: linux, synchronization, rootfs

I have several testing computers and I want to automaticaly synchronize content of their root filesystems. What are the possible ways to do it? I am changing not only userspace applications and data but alse the Kernel will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

rsync is probably what you want, and Arch wiki has a good, general purpose, document for rsyncing the root directory [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync).

That being said, doing what you're suggesting may render your systems unusable if hardware differs enough to make configuration files different.